# How to create list of Mail messages to move together rather than moving them individually?

Tags: applescript

I've managed to make this AppleScript work. It basically searches my inboxes for all my accounts and then selects any messages from specific address that are older than 14 days. It then proceeds to move each one of those filtered messages to a specified mailbox.

```
set ExcludeList to {"Trash", "Sent", "Drafts", "Deleted Messages", "Archive", "Junk", "Notes"} -- mailboxes you don't want to search
set SenderList to {"events@goldstar.com", "hello@touchofmodern.com", "staples@e.staples.com", "deals@livingsocial.com"} -- email addresses of senders you want to remove old emails for
set DestinationFolderName to "Old_Newsletters" -- mailbox to move messages to. If you want to just delete them, leave it blank.
set StaleTime to 14 -- days old the message must be before moved or deleted
set ShowMailboxesProgress to true -- determines if you want the "Processing" box displayed for each mailbox
set current_date to current date
set _msgs_to_move to {}

tell application "Mail"
    set everyAccount to every account where enabled is true

    -- Get acount-specific mailboxes
    repeat with eachAccount in everyAccount
        set accountName to the name of eachAccount
        set currentMailbox to mailbox "INBOX" of eachAccount
        set mailboxName to the name of currentMailbox
        if mailboxName is not in ExcludeList then
            if ShowMailboxesProgress then
                display dialog "Processing folder " & mailboxName & " in account " & accountName
            end if
            try
                repeat with SenderToRemove in SenderList
                    set messages_list to (every message of currentMailbox whose sender ends with "<" & SenderToRemove & ">")
                    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in messages_list
                        set theMessage to item i of messages_list
                        set difference to ((current_date) - (date sent of theMessage)) div days
                        if difference is greater than StaleTime then
                            if DestinationFolderName is not equal to "" then
                                move theMessage to mailbox DestinationFolderName of account "BlueStar Studios"
                            else
                                delete theMessage
                            end if
                        end if
                    end repeat
                end repeat
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
    display dialog "Finished!"
end tell
```

It seems to work nice. HOWEVER, it takes a long time to run. Because it moves each filtered message individually. Is there a way to make a list of messages to be moved while in the repeat and then move that entire list of messages to another folder in one go?

Also, I'm running on 10.7.5 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a filter reference form like this:

```
set d to (current date) - 14 * days
tell application "Mail"
    repeat with a in (get accounts where enabled is true)
        move (messages of mailbox "INBOX" of account a where date sent < d and (sender ends with "<events@goldstar.com>" or sender ends with "<hello@touchofmodern.com>")) to mailbox "Old_Newsletters" of account "BlueStar Studios"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: That worked fantastic! Totally scaled down the code and sped up the process! THANKS.
The only note I will make is that with this setup, the move command should read:
`move (messages of mailbox "INBOX" of a where date sent...`
having "account a" yields an error.